# How to populate a matrix in Python with variable values instead of just 0

Tags: python, list, matrix

I am trying to create an m by n matrix in Python that will be populated by multiplying the row by the column. So myMatrix[0] would be 1, myMatrix[1] would be 2, ect.

```
m = int(input("What width is your matrix? "))
type(m)
n = int(input("What height is your matrix? "))
type(n)

myMatrix = [[0. for x in range(m)] for y in range(n)]
```

If I print my matrix everything looks good so far, all the values are 0 and it is the correct dimensions. I noticed I could play around with "0." and get different values (Like 1+0 would put all 1.0s, ect) but what I cannot seem to figure out is how to put a variable there instead.

Ideally I would want to do something that multiples the row by the column, but I can't seem to find the syntax to accomplish that. Any idea or direction? Are you able to put anything in the matrix creation where "0." is or can you only do static integers?

Comment: What is the expected output for, say, 4x4?

Comment: You can put any expression there, it doesn't have to be a literal. `x * y`, for example.

Comment: In your case: myMatrix = [[ x * y for x in range(m)] for y in range(n)]

Comment: @coldspeed The expected output for 4x4 would be a matrix that is 4 long and 4 tall. If you're asking about row 4, column 4, that would be the value 16 in that element of the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Everything<sup>1</sup> is an object in Python. So you can put anything in place of `0`:

```
[[int for x in range(m)] for y in range(n)]       # int class
[[{} for x in range(m)] for y in range(n)]        # empty dictionary
[['hello' for x in range(m)] for y in range(n)]   # string
[[-51.237 for x in range(m)] for y in range(n)]   # float
```

Any expression which evaluates to an object may also be used:

```
[[x**y for x in range(m)] for y in range(n)]        # x to the power of y
[[x*y for x in range(m)] for y in range(n)]         # x multiplied by y
[[abs(x-y) for x in range(m)] for y in range(n)]    # absolute difference between x and y
[['a'*abs(int(x)) for x in range(m)] for y in range(n)]  # string abs(int(x)) times
```

Be careful with terminology. Matrix is not a Python built-in, the term doesn't exist in regular Python lexicon. You are using a `list` of `list` objects. A matrix (or now, array) is more usually used with reference to a 3rd party library called NumPy.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Well, *almost* everything: for example, `if` is a keyword, not an object. But functions, classes, class instances are all objects.</sup>